# Create function for linear regression in R for n parameter using matrix method

Tags: r, function, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to create linear regression  function in R for n parameter  but I don't know how to proceed.I have created function for two variable.
]

```r
new_lm <- function(y,x){
  z=cbind(1,x)
  k= solve(t(z)%*%z) %*% t(z) %*% y
  return(k)
}
```

But in this case  I am passing the values suppose I wanted to use it for n parameter that is same function can be used for n=1,2.. etc.

Comment: Can you give a [mcve]?  If `x` is a matrix it will just work.  Are you OK with that or do you need a function that will work with `new_lm(y,x1)` or `new_lm(y,x1,x2)` or `new_lm(y,x1,x2,x3)` ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```r
new_lm <- function(y,...){
  x <- do.call(cbind, list(...))
  z <- cbind(1,x)
  k <- solve(t(z)%*%z) %*% t(z) %*% y
  return(k)
}
```

By the way, computing linear regressions this way is terrible in practice (although for small problems it will work fine); you should use QR or singular value decomposition, or some other more sophisticated bit of linear algebra ...